# Access Denied for database when using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, shell, jdbc, mariadb

I am working on a simple mariaDB database called `movieDB` and there is a mariaDB user called `customerAgent`. I know there are many similar on StackOverflow, but I am not using a *root* account, but a normal account with minimum granted privileges.

---

I can access the database `movieDB` in terminal via SSH like this:

```
[root@myServer]# mysql -ucustomerAgent -p123

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 102
Server version: 10.2.12-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> USE movieDB;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [movieDB]> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for customerAgent@localhost                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT Customer_Role TO 'customerAgent'@'localhost'                                                                   |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'customerAgent'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257'       |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'Customer_Role'                                                                                      |
| GRANT SELECT ON `movieDB`.* TO 'Customer_Role'                                                                             |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `movieDB`.`orders` TO 'Customer_Role'                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [movieDB]> select current_role();
+----------------+
| current_role() |
+----------------+
| Customer_Role  |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [movieDB]>
```

---

But when I execute JDBC codes on localhost, access is denied at the line `stmt.execute("USE movieDB");`:

```
Access denied for user 'customerAgent'@'localhost' to database 'movidDB'
```

The java JDBC codes are: (I have removed some unnecessaries in the class, but in the case that I missed anything important, please do point out!)

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

Class movieDBFoundation {
    static private String DBServerAddress = "localhost";
    static private Connection conn;

    static private String getDBServerAddress() {
        return DBServerAddress;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Connection started.");

        if(DBConnect()) {
            System.out.println("Connection succedded.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Connection failed.");
            return;
        }            
    }

    static private Boolean DBConnect() {
        String connectString = "jdbc:mysql://" + getDBServerAddress() + ":3306/"
              + "?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&&useSSL=false";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "customerAgent", "123");
            System.out.println("Connection reached.");
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String SQL = "USE movidDB";
            stmt.execute(SQL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Some answers in similar questions say JDBC need **all** privileges on a database, but that does not sound very safe nor secure. Is it a must to have all privileges to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Have you read the exception? `movidDB` != `movieDB`...

Comment: Yeah, I did read the exception and how stupid was I that I missed the typo!!!

Comment: OMG, I spent the whole afternoon looking for answers on dozens of Googles searches and SO answers...

Comment: You should never use command like `USE <databasename>` when using JDBC, you should either connect directly to movieDB by specifying that in the URL, or use `setCatalog(..)`, see also the [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#idm140034247545376). Using `use <database-name>` may leave a connection in an incorrect state, which could lead to bugs that are hard to identify later on.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, Mark! Really appreciate your advice! I’m rewriting the connection part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the database **movidDB** don't exist. Should it not be **movieDB**?

Comment: Yes, it should be **movieDB**!! I feel so dumb that I should missed that!  Just made a New Record in 2018, and a really ridiculous one!

Comment: And it's saved for eternity here on SO. Well done :)